# Grails is not working even when grails-wrapper.jar is updated

Tags: gradle, grails, spring-security

I has to install spring security in my grails 3 application and started receiving that known error which should be resolved by replacing grails-wrapper.jar.

That is the error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'cmberp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.11.
     Required by:
         :cmberp:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.11.
         > Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/3.3.11/grails-gradle-plugin-3.3.11.pom'.
            > For input string: "<ht"
```

So I followed the steps in https://grails.org/blog/2021-06-10-grails-wrapper-update.html and replaced grails-wrapper.jar in /media/alfredo/1TBHDD/CMB/Code projects/Grails 3/plataforma-mserp/grails-wrapper.jar by that one for Grails 3 version commented in the deocument.

After it I reviewed my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            //maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core" }
            maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath files('gradle/gradle-trust-all.jar')
            classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
            classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
            classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.6"
            classpath "net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1"
            classpath 'io.github.robwin:jgitflow-gradle-plugin:0.6.0'
        }
}

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()    
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
```

The only difference is that I use http instead of https. I tried with https but I had a lot of other problems.

Anyone could help?

Thanks

Alfredo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is all related to the repo URL problems over the last week or so.  More info is here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825 but in general it sounds like the `http` URLs are either going away, or gone already.

Specifically reference https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825#issuecomment-859692299 in which Jeff Brown states

> If the HTTP URLs do resume working without a redirect that will be for a limited period. I would not suggest reverting any updates you have already made to the HTTPS repository URLs. I would also strongly consider taking the time to update your remaining applications.

Change to `https` and come back with whatever problems you run into then...I would expect someone here can help work through those.

Comment: Thank you. When I replace http by https it works. The problem is with Spring security. I will post another question about that.